# Fetch data from Firebase by joining tables in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, completionhandler

I am trying to fetch data from two different Firebase tables. Here is the structure of table:

```
Post {
    1{
       pImages{
           i1:true
           i2:true
       }
    }
    2{
       pImages{
           i3:true

       }
    }
}
Images{
       i1{
          iUrl : ....
          pId : 1
         }
       i2{
          iUrl :...
          pId : 1
         }
       i3{
         iUrl:....
          pId : 2
         }
 }
```

I need to retrieve images corresponding to post with id = 1. The following is my implementation to retrieve images:

```
 func retrieveImagesForPost(postId: String,completion: (result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?)->()){
        var imgArray:[Image]=[]
        let postsRef = self.ref.child("post")
        let imagesRef = self.ref.child("image")
        let postImagesRef = postsRef.child(postId).child("pImages");
        postImagesRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            for item in snapshot.children{
                imagesRef.child(item.key).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in
                    let image = Image(snapshot: snap)
                    print(image)
                    imgArray.append(image)
                })
            }
            print(snapshot.key)
            print("called")
            completion(result:imgArray, error:nil)
        })
    }
```

But, the problem is I am not able to get all images in `imgArray` to be able to send to `completion handler`. Below is the output of calling `retrieveImagesForPost` with post id ==1.

```
pImages
called
<TestProject.Image: 0x7f9551e82000>
<TestProject.Image: 0x7f955466a150>
```

The images are retrieved after the `completion handler` is called. I tried the `dispatch groups` and the `semaphores` approach as described in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906568/wait-until-swift-for-loop-with-asynchronous-network-requests-finishes-executing). But the results are still the same. How can I make `completion handler` to wait for all images to be fetched from Firebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep a counter that you increase as each image is loaded. Once the counter reaches the length of the `snapshot.children` list, you're done and call your completion handler.

```
let postImagesRef = postsRef.child(postId).child("pImages");
postImagesRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    var counter = 0
    for item in snapshot.children{
        imagesRef.child(item.key).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snap) in
            let image = Image(snapshot: snap)
            print(image)
            imgArray.append(image)
            counter = counter + 1
            if (counter == snapshot.childrenCount) {
                completion(result:imgArray, error:nil)
            }
        })
    }
})
```

You should probably add some error handling in the above, but in general this approach is tried and tested.

Comment: how does your function change i would need to join 3 nodes (relationships) in Firebase

Comment: if (counter == snapshot.childrenCount)  throws an error!?

Answer (score 1):

Another answer for this problem is to use GCD's `DispatchGroup`.

First you need to create a dispatch group with `DispatchGroup`. In this case, you need to manually tell the group when work is being started with `enter()` and when it's finished with `leave()`. Then the dispatch group's `notify(queue:execute:)` will execute the completion handler on the main queue.

Be careful! The number of enters and leaves must be balanced or the dispatch group's notify will never be called.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

let postImagesRef = postsRef.child(postId).child("pImages");
postImagesRef.observeEventType(FIRDataEventType.value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    for item in snapshot.children{
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        imagesRef.child(item.key).observeSingleEventOfType(.value, withBlock: { (snap) in
            let image = Image(snapshot: snap)
            print(image)
            imgArray.append(image)
            dispatchGroup.leave()
        })
    }
})

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    completion(result: imgArray)
})
```

Comment: This is much better than using a counter, as in the accepted answer. Though, for it to work properly, the `dispatchGroup` must be instantiated inside the first observe block, and notified after the `for`. Entering and leaving the group is correct.